# What is the z-transform of $x(k) =(-2)^k \cdot u(k+2)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, z-transform

I have been trying to figure this one for quite some time now.
I tried using the following formula: 
$x(k) \iff X(z) = \frac{z}{z-a}$ , when $|z|>|a|$

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is the function $u(k)$?